# How to return different Response Types using Factory / Strategy pattern

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, strategy-pattern, abstract-factory

Objective: I want to implement multiple Payment Processors. (Language: C#)

Design Choice: I chose the Strategy Pattern. It helped in calling the appropriate payment processor.

Problem: Different payment processor returns different responses. I had to create seperate Process() method per Processor.

I tried to unify all the response in a single interface but the interface has so many properties and I'm not sure if there is a better way.

```
public class PaymentStrategy
{
    public static IPaymentProcessor GetPaymentType(IPaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        if (paymentDetails.PaymentType == PaymentTypes.PaymentProcessorA)
            return new PaymentProcessorA();
        else if (paymentDetails.PaymentType == PaymentTypes.PaymentProcessorA)
            return new PaymentProcessorA();
        else if (paymentDetails.PaymentType == PaymentTypes.PayPal)
            return new PayPal();
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PaymentService : IPaymentService
{
    public IPaymentDetails PaymentDetails { get; set; }
    public IPaymentProcessor PaymentProcessor { get; set; }

    public PaymentService(IPaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        PaymentDetails = paymentDetails;
        PaymentProcessor = PaymentStrategy.GetPaymentType(paymentDetails);
    }

    public PaymentA_Response Process_A()
    {
        return PaymentProcessor.Process_A(PaymentDetails); 
    }

    public PaymentB_Response Process_B()
    {
        return PaymentProcessor.Process_B(PaymentDetails); 
    }

}

internal class PaymentProcessorA : IPaymentProcessor
{
    public string GetPaymentGatewayName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }       

    public PaymentA_Response Process(IPaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        return new PaymentA_Response() { TxId = 1, ResponseFromA = $"Success from {GetType().Name}" };
    }   
}

internal class PaymentProcessorB : IPaymentProcessor
{
    public string GetPaymentGatewayName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }       

    public PaymentB_Response Process(IPaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        return new PaymentB_Response() { TxId = 1, ResponseFromB = $"Success from {GetType().Name}" };
    }   
}

class PaymentA_Response
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}

class PaymentB_Response
{
    public int Tx { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string F { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }
    public string H { get; set; }
    public string I { get; set; }
    public string J { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPaymentGateway();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestPaymentGateway()
    {
        // Calling code for PaymentGateway A
        IPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails()
        {
            Amount = 10,
            PaymentType = PaymentTypes.PaymentProcessorA
        };

        PaymentService paymentService = new PaymentService(paymentDetails);
        Process_A_Response resopnse = paymentService.Process_A();

        Console.WriteLine(resopnse.A);

        // Calling code for PaymentGateway B
        IPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PaymentDetails()
        {
            Amount = 10,
            PaymentType = PaymentTypes.PaymentProcessorB
        };

        PaymentService paymentService = new PaymentService(paymentDetails);
        Process_B_Response resopnse = paymentService.Process_B();

        Console.WriteLine(resopnse.F);
    }   
}
```

Solution Needed: 
I want the client code to call a method named Process() using PaymentService class that returns a single response object instead of calling process_A or Process_B.

Comment: Could you reformulate to ask an actual question?

Comment: @Webber I changed the question a bit to make it clear. Let me know if you still need clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can have generic interface in place to handle it so that one `Process` method can handle it :

```
public class PaymentService<TResponse> : IPaymentService<TResponse>
{
    public IPaymentDetails PaymentDetails { get; set; }
    public IPaymentProcessor PaymentProcessor { get; set; }

    public PaymentService(IPaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        PaymentDetails = paymentDetails;
        PaymentProcessor = PaymentStrategy.GetPaymentType(paymentDetails);
    }

    public TResponse Process()
    {
        return PaymentProcessor.Process(PaymentDetails); 
    }


}
```

and on calling side you will need to specify the response type:

```
var service = new PaymentService<PaymentA_Response>();
var response = service.Process();
```

The above snippet is just to give idea how you can use generic type parameter to incorporate it using one method in service. You might need changes at other places as well.

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad,  Thank you. The solution eliminates the need of calling different method per payment type. However, it still has to mention the Response type when calling the PaymentService such as 'var service = new PaymentService<PaymentA_Response>();' Do you think if there is a way to eliminate this ? Thanks again.

Comment: @BSoc that type you need to specify as type parameter as it is different in all cases, if there was something common we can have it as another common interface or class

Comment: if there is possibilty to make a common class or interface for all service responses, then we can eliminate some way the Response type